Determine the eccentricity of a particular hyperbola.
This is a question I found about conic curves.

A hyperbola, with equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ and left focus $F$, intersects with a line passing through the origin at points $A, B$. Given that $|FB|=2|FA|$ and $\vec{FA}\cdot\vec{FB}=4a^2$, what is the value of the eccentricity of the hyperbola?

I first substituted $y=kx$ into the equation of the hyperbola, but the calculation got complex. Maybe another method could be useful apart from substitution.

I found a way of another method.
First, it is easy to notice that $A$ and $B$ are symmetric about the origin. So we assume that $A (-X,-Y)$ and $B(X,Y)$. $(X>0)$
Because the two points lie on the curve, we have $A,B$ satisfying
$$\frac{X^2}{a^2}-\frac{Y^2}{b^2}=1\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
According to the definition of hyperbola, we know that $|FA|$ equals to the distance from $A$ to the directrix $y=-\frac{a^2}c$, that is
$$|FA|=X-\frac{a^2}c$$
The same for $|FB|$:
$$|FB|=X+\frac{a^2}c$$
Then we have
$$X+\frac{a^2}c=2X-\frac{2a^2}c$$
$$\Rightarrow X=\frac{3a^2}c\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
And we also know that $\vec{FA}\cdot\vec{FB}=(\vec{FO}+\vec{OA})(\vec{FO}+\vec{OB})=(\vec{FO}+\vec{OA})(\vec{FO}-\vec{OA})={|FO|}^2-{|OA|}^2=c^2-(X^2+Y^2)$, so we have
$$c^2-(X^2+Y^2)=4a^2\tag{3}\label{eq3}$$
Combining $(1),(2),(3)$ and substitute $b^2=c^2-a^2$, we have
$$14a^2=2c^2$$
$$e=\frac ca=\sqrt7$$
